# Excel: VBA code to DISABLE "Clear ALL or Clear Filters"

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a protected Workbook & Pivot table in an excel file on a filter that I'm sending to certain users based on the filter.
( Drill down is on, but Field List and Field Dialogs are turned off).

**I want to disable these buttons "CLEAR FILTERS or CLEAR ALL", would anyone know of a code?**

Thank you!

Comment: If its the data you want to hide... You better delete it. If you want the user to refilter ... Add a button that resets the filter

Comment: I only want the user to view the data I'm allowing them to view, which is why everything is protected.

I need pivot table drill down functionality, but everything else needs to be protected.  I have measures in a PowerPivot / Pivot Table calculated and everything is in one file.

Ultimately I don't want the user to be able to "Clear Filter" and see other data since I have lots of data and unable to break them out without spending lots of time doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: a quick fix is to read all data from another sheet e. g "=A1" etc. and set the pivot sheet to very hidden in vbe... but this is not elegant nor good performence solution.